# Some problem with alignment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I got a little problem with alignment [image]

Kkkkkk should be exactly over the Nnnnnnnn and centerlines over each other.

Code of the first line:

```
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[5,l]X[1,l]X[4,c]X[1,c]X[3,r]}
  Научный руководитель  &  &  &  & \\
  к-т эконом. наук, доцент  &  &  &  & О.N. Nnnnnnnn \\ \cline{3-3}
  &  & \centerline{\small{подпись, дата}} &  &  \\
\end{tabu}
\vspace{4.5cm}
```

and the second line:

```
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[l,5]X[5,l]X[4,c]X[1,c]X[r,3]}
  Руководитель темы  &  &  &  & И.И. Kkkkkk \\ \cline{3-3}
  &  & \centerline{\small{подпись, дата}} &  &  \\
\end{tabu}
```

Comment: You should put `\noindent` before each `tabu`. And I think you should make the `tabu` headers the same. Now the first one has `X[1,l]` for the second column and the second one has `X[5,l]`. So the sizes are different.

Answer (score 1):

Use boxes, it's much easier than exploiting `tabu`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
  \makebox[.36\textwidth][l]{Научный руководитель}%
  \hfill
  \parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{%
    \centering
    \hrulefill\par
    \small подпись, дата
  }%
  \hfill
  \makebox[.21\textwidth][r]{О.N. Nnnnnnnn}%
}

\bigskip

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
  \makebox[.36\textwidth][l]{Руководитель темы}%
  \hfill
  \parbox[t]{.29\textwidth}{%
    \centering
    \hrulefill\par
    \small подпись, дата
  }%
  \hfill
  \makebox[.21\textwidth][r]{И.И. Kkkkkk}%
}

\end{document}
```

I have used the same proportions: 5/14 for the leftmost box, 4/14 for the middle box and 3/14 for the rightmost box.

The frame is used just to show the text is at the left and right margins.

[image]

Comment: Its dont compile. Look https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRZ0t.jpg

Comment: @PersonaNonGrata I suspect some bogus character somewhere.